# JavaScript- Plotly is not defined

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to use Plotly using javascript, but despite including script file I get Plotly name recognising error. I want to include plotly from file to use project offline (here is the link I downloaded: https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js ), however using *"plotly.js CDN"* gives the same result.
To explain the rest of script paths (*"node_modules/*"*) - all scripts instead of *plotly* were installed using *npm*, however it's not nodejs project.
Had someone this kind of ploblem? Please help me, I don't know what should I do :/

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Function extremum</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- custom css and js: -->
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="eel-communication.js"></script>
        <link href="components/control-area/control-area.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="components/control-subareas/algorithm-control-subarea.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="components/view-area/view-area.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="components/control-area/control-area.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="components/view-area/view-area.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="components/control-subareas/algorithm-control-subarea.js"></script>
        <!-- include components -->
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="layout" class="secondary-color-bg h-100 w-100">
            <!-- <div id="background-image"></div> -->
            <div id="control-area" class="left"></div>
            <div id="view-area" class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tester"></div>
    </body>
    <script> 
        TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');
    Plotly.newPlot( TESTER, [{
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16] }], {
    margin: { t: 0 } } );
    
        $(function(){
          $("#control-area").load("components/control-area/control-area.html"); 
          $("#view-area").load("components/view-area/view-area.html");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

**Error:**

```
index.html:36 Uncaught ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined
    at index.html:36
```

Comment: The `<script>` element has to be a child of `<head>` or `<body>`

Comment: When I run that code it says `newPlot` is not defined and nothing about `Plotly`. You should provide a [mcve] the demonstrates your problem (and do be *minimal*: don't include links to a stack of JS that isn't relevant to the issue).

Comment: Ok, thank you guys! I moved script section to body as You said. Then I moved <script src="pyplot-latest.min.js"> above the rest of <script> tags. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I moved script section to body, then I moved  above the rest of  tags. Now it works!